# Copy textfile using fwrite, ending up with trash? C

Tags: c, copy, fwrite

Iam trying to  copy a text file to a new file. I was thinking that if I want to do it smart, I just copy everything binary so the copy will be identical to the first. However I'am ending up with weird character in the new document.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE * fporgi, * fpcopy;


    if((fporgi = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL){
            //Error checking
        fprintf(stdout, "Error occurred trying to open file :%s", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if((fpcopy = fopen(argv[2], "wb")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stdout, "Error occurred trying to open file :%s", argv[2]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    long bytes;

    fseek(fporgi, 0L, SEEK_END); 
    bytes = ftell(fporgi);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n%ld\n", bytes);

    unsigned char buffer[bytes]; 
    fprintf(stdout, "\n%u\n", sizeof(buffer));
    fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fporgi); 
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fpcopy);

    fclose(fporgi);
    fclose(fpcopy);

    return 0;
}
```

Example if the original file contains "hej svej" the new file will have : "(œÌuR0@NUL"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a short sample of input and resulting output junk. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: How big is the file? Did the number shown for `sizeof(buffer)` match the actual file size? Also, you should be checking the return values from `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: It matches the amout of characters i have in the text file. If i have the letters : "hej svej" in the first file. The result of the second will be : (œÌuR0@NUL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to seek back to the start of the file after reading the length:

```
fseek(fporgi, 0L, SEEK_END); 
bytes = ftell(fporgi);
fprintf(stdout, "\n%ld\n", bytes);
fseek(fporgi, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```